# Espresso - Difference between not(isDisplayed()) vs doesNotExist()

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso, android-architecture

I was reading a [todoapp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvp-room/todoapp/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksScreenTest.java) from Android architectural blueprints when I came across these two tests. I cant seem to understand that why is it necessary to use `doesNotExist()` in `createTwoTasks_deleteOneTask()`, to check that an item with the specified title is deleted, when it is totally okay to use `not(isDisplayed())` in `createOneTask_deleteTask()` for checking the same thing?

```
@Test
public void createOneTask_deleteTask() {
    viewAllTasks();

    // Add active task
    createTask(TITLE1, DESCRIPTION);

    // Open it in details view
    onView(withText(TITLE1)).perform(click());

    // Click delete task in menu
    onView(withId(R.id.menu_delete)).perform(click());

    // Verify it was deleted
    viewAllTasks();
    onView(withText(TITLE1)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
}

@Test
public void createTwoTasks_deleteOneTask() {
    // Add 2 active tasks
    createTask(TITLE1, DESCRIPTION);
    createTask(TITLE2, DESCRIPTION);

    // Open the second task in details view
    onView(withText(TITLE2)).perform(click());

    // Click delete task in menu
    onView(withId(R.id.menu_delete)).perform(click());

    // Verify only one task was deleted
    viewAllTasks();
    onView(withText(TITLE1)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText(TITLE2)).check(doesNotExist());
}
```

I am new in Espresso testing but I know that usually `doesNotExist()` is called to confirm that a view is Gone but then why `not(isDisplayed())` is working fine even when the view has been removed? I tried to use `doesNotExist()` but it throws a error.

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: View is present in the hierarchy: AppCompatTextView{id=2131624010, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1120, height=107, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=256.0, y=74.0, text=TITLE1, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
Expected: is <false>
Got: <true>

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksScreenTest.createOneTask_deleteTask(TasksScreenTest.java:284)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1959)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: View is present in the hierarchy: AppCompatTextView{id=2131624010, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1120, height=107, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=256.0, y=74.0, text=TITLE1, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
Expected: is <false>
Got: <true>

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:1053)
at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$1.check(ViewAssertions.java:62)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: There are 3 states for a View: Visible, Invisible, and Gone. `Invisible` will reserve a place in the View but will not be shown, to detect it, you'll need to use `isDisplayed()`. `Gone` in the other hand, will not be drawn or reserve a place in the View, and so we use `doesNotExist()` to make sure it is not there.

Comment: Yeah okay right, then?

Comment: In code they are creating a task, remove it from the repo, move back to the previous activity, and then force to load tasks again from the repo..
When using espresso to test this scenario, they are using `doesNotExist()` when only a single task is created but using `not(isDisplayed())` when creating two tasks, deleting one of them and then moving back to the previous activity to check if the second has been deleted or not

Comment: Are you using the auto testing to generate the code?

Comment: Sir, this code is not written by me. I said that it is a sample made by some developers in Google for teaching Android architecture and testing.
Here is the link to the repo: [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/dev-todo-mvp-room)
And here is the link to the test file: [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvp-room/todoapp/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksScreenTest.java)